# Pymongo: Cannot encode object of type decimal.Decimal?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, decimal, pymongo

After trying to [insert_one](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) into a collection. I receive this error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: Decimal('0.16020'), of type: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

The code runs fine when the JSON does not include the `decimal.Decimal` object. If there is a solution can you kindly consider coding it in a recursive manner to made the whole of the python dictionary `json_dic` compatible to be inserted into MongoDB (as there is more than once instance of the class decimal.Decimal in the `json.dic` entries).

**EDIT 1:** Here is the JSON I am dealing with

```
import simplejson as json
from pymongo import MongoClient

json_string = '{"A" : {"B" : [{"C" : {"Horz" : 0.181665435,"Vert" : 0.178799435}}]}}'

json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
this_collection.insert_one(json_dict)
```

This produces
`bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: Decimal('0.181665435'), of type: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>`

**EDIT 2:** Unfortunately my example above simplified my existing JSON too much and the answer provided by @[Belly Buster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61461289/157416) (despite working fine with the Json above) thows an error:

`AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'items'`

with my actual JSON, so I am providing the full JSON here hopefully to find out what is wrong (also [as a screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ysYP.png)):

```
json_string = 
'
{
  "Setting" : {
    "GridOptions" : {
      "Student" : "HighSchool",
      "Lesson" : 1,
      "Attended" : true
    },
    "Grades" : [
      80,
      50.75
    ],
    "Count" : 2,
    "Check" : "Coursework",
    "Passed" : true
  },
  "Slides" : [
    {
      "Type" : "ABC",
      "Duration" : 1.5
    },
    {
      "Type" : "DEF",
      "Duration" : 0.5
    }
  ],
  "Work" : {
    "Class" : [
      {
        "Time" : 123456789,
        "Marks" : {
          "A" : 50,
          "B" : 100
        }
      }
    ],
    "CourseWorkDetail" : [
      {
        "Test" : {
          "Mark" : 0.987654321
        },
        "ReadingDate" : "Feb162006",
        "Reading" : 300.001,
        "Values" : [
          [
            0.98765
          ],
          [
            -0.98765
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "Test" : {
          "Mark" : 0.123456789
        },
        "ReadingDate" : "Jan052010",
        "Reading" : 200.005,
        "Values" : [
          [
            0.12345
          ],
          [
            -0.12345
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "listing" : 5
}
'
```

**Edit 3:**
Complimentary to the answer below, you can iterate recursively in a dictionary like this and use the function from the answer

```
def iterdict(dict_items, debug_out):
    for k, v in dict_items.items():
        if isinstance(v):
            iterdict(v)
        else:
            dict_items[k] = convert_decimal(v)
    return dict_items
```

Comment: Please update your post with the code you tried.

Comment: I have added the code now

Comment: Your added code runs without error on mongo version 4.2. What version are you running? Did you run that exact code (don't see any connection lines)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT:

The `convert_decimal()` function will perform the conversion of Decimal to Decimal128 within a complex dict structure:

```
import simplejson as json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from decimal import Decimal
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128

def convert_decimal(dict_item):
    # This function iterates a dictionary looking for types of Decimal and converts them to Decimal128
    # Embedded dictionaries and lists are called recursively.
    if dict_item is None: return None

    for k, v in list(dict_item.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            convert_decimal(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for l in v:
                convert_decimal(l)
        elif isinstance(v, Decimal):
            dict_item[k] = Decimal128(str(v))

    return dict_item

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
json_string = '{"A" : {"B" : [{"C" : {"Horz" : 0.181665435,"Vert" : 0.178799435}}]}}'
json_dict = json.loads(json_string, use_decimal=True)
db.this_collection.insert_one(convert_decimal(json_dict))
print(db.this_collection.find_one())
```

gives:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5ea743aa297c9ccd52d33e05'), 'A': {'B': [{'C': {'Horz': Decimal128('0.181665435'), 'Vert': Decimal128('0.178799435')}}]}}
```

ORIGINAL:

To convert a decimal to a Decimal128 that MongoDB will be happy with, convert it to a string and then to a Decimal128. This snippet may help:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from decimal import Decimal
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
your_number = Decimal('234.56')
your_number_128 = Decimal128(str(your_number))
db.mycollection.insert_one({'Number': your_number_128})
print(db.mycollection.find_one())
```

gives:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5ea6ec9b52619c7b39b851cb'), 'Number': Decimal128('234.56')}
```

Comment: Thanks Belly, I am given the Json string and I am not contstructing it on the go, is there a way I can apply your answer to an existing string? I have  updated the original question with my actual Json schema. Many thanks!

Comment: thank you for that function that works perfectly. In my silliness I thought I could provide a smaller picture of what the actual Json is (which your code works perfectly on) but would you kinldy have a look at the larger Json I have updated the question with. For some reason while iterating recursively in that Json your function throws this:  `AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'items'` Would you kindly have a look to see how your function could be updated to do the same on this longer Json string? Many thanks again!!

Comment: Lookup a function that will recurse a nested dict structure and use a combination of that and my answer. Will be a good learning experience!

Comment: Thanks @Belly Buster

Answer (score 1):

Pymongo doesn't recognize `Decimal` - that's why you are getting the error.

The correct pymongo insert is `coll.insert_one({"number1": Decimal128('8.916')})`.

You'll also need the import - `from bson import Decimal128`

Now, if you want to process your JSON file without changing `Decimal` to Decimal128`, you could modify the import statement.

```py
from bson import Decimal128 as Decimal

coll.insert_one({"number1": Decimal('8.916')})
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, I would like to dynamicllay insert he Json data but I am working with an existing Json string. Is there a way I can apply your answer to an existing string recursively? I have now updated the original question with my actual Json schema. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128, create_decimal128_context
from decimal import localcontext

decimal128_ctx = create_decimal128_context()
with localcontext(decimal128_ctx) as ctx:
    horiz_val = Decimal128(ctx.create_decimal("0.181665435"))
    vert_val = Decimal128(ctx.create_decimal("0.178799435"))

doc = { 'A': { 'B': [ { 'C': { 'Horiz': horiz_val, 'Vert': vert_val } } ] } }
result = collection.insert_one(doc)
# result.inserted_id

pprint.pprint(list(collection.find()))

[ {'A': {'B': [{'C': {'Horiz': Decimal128('0.181665435'),
                      'Vert': Decimal128('0.178799435')}}]},
  '_id': ObjectId('5ea79adb915cbf3c46f5d4ae')} ]
```

NOTES:

- PyMongo's [decimal128 - Support for BSON Decimal128](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/decimal128.html)
- Python's [decimal
  module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)
  provides support for decimal floating point arithmetic.

From the PyMongo's decimal128 documentation:

> To ensure the result of a calculation can always be stored as BSON
>   Decimal128 use the context returned by `create_decimal128_context()` (NOTE: as shown in the example code above).

Comment: Thanks prasad_, this code works fine if I was contstucting the Json variable but I am given it in a file, so I need to itteratively change the values in it after importing it. Belly Buster's answer, gives a function that does that but it doesnt work on my longer more complex Json. I have updated the question to include that longer Json. Is there a function that could iteratively update the values in a string Json that are not compatible with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just adding a codec to automatically convert the data types at insertion. If you recursively change the data types to use the Decimal128 object you might break compatibility with existing code.

You can follow the tutorial to create a simple decimal.Decimal codec in the pymongo docs [here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/custom_type.html)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61461289/14693246) is partially correct but fails our tests written with `pytest` with the example data:

```
example = {
    "string_field": "some",
    "string_array_list": ["samatta"],
    "decimal_containing_list": ["a", Decimal(8)],
    "empty_list": [],
    "empty_dict": {},
    "direct_decimal": Decimal(0),
    "nested_decimal_dict": {"very_important-field": Decimal(1)},
    "number_field": 1,
    "nested_number_field": {"very_important-field": 1},
    "number_list": [1, 2],
    "decimal_containing_field_list": [{"very_important": Decimal(1)}],
}
```

where nested arrays are the case. I improved it a little bit, and current one passess the tests:

```
from typing import Union
    
def convert_decimal(item: Union[dict, list]) -> Union[dict, list]:
    if item is None:
        return None

    elif isinstance(item, list):
        for index, item in enumerate(item):
            if isinstance(item, Decimal):
                item[index] = Decimal128(str(item))
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                convert_decimal(item)
        return item

    elif isinstance(item, dict):
        for k, v in list(item.items()):
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                convert_decimal(v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                convert_decimal(v)
            elif isinstance(v, Decimal):
                item[k] = Decimal128(str(v))

        return item
```

when you print it out it gives,

```
{
    "string_field": "some",
    "string_array_list": ["samatta"],
    "decimal_containing_list": ["a", Decimal128("8")],
    "empty_list": [],
    "empty_dict": {},
    "direct_decimal": Decimal128("0"),
    "nested_decimal_dict": {"very_important-field": Decimal128("1")},
    "number_field": 1,
    "nested_number_field": {"very_important-field": 1},
    "number_list": [1, 2],
    "decimal_containing_field_list": [{"very_important": Decimal128("1")}],
}
```