# Unable to convert decimal to Decimal128 in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymssql

My Django project (python==3.10.3, Django==4.0.4) is accessing an MSSQL server via pymssql (pymssql==2.2.5), scraping what I need, and getting a list of dicts.
I then save to MongoDB (pymongo==4.2.0) but there are decimal values that need to be Decimal128. I found [Pymongo: Cannot encode object of type decimal.Decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456784/pymongo-cannot-encode-object-of-type-decimal-decimal) which has a similar goal as mine. So I adapted to handle the list of dict like this:

```
def convert_decimal_iterdict(list_of_dict):
    if list_of_dict is None:
        return None

    for i in list_of_dict:
        for k, v in i.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                convert_decimal_iterdict(v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for l in v:
                    convert_decimal_iterdict(l)
            elif isinstance(v, Decimal):
                list_of_dict[k] = Decimal128(str(v))

    return list_of_dict
```

It errors with

```
   list_of_dict[k] = Decimal128(str(v))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So I attempted to use Decimal, float, or int...

```
                list_of_dict[k] = Decimal128(Decimal(v))
```

but get

```
#Decimal
   raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal128" % (value,))
TypeError: Cannot convert 1 to Decimal128

#float
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal128" % (value,))
TypeError: Cannot convert 1.0 to Decimal128

#int
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal128" % (value,))
TypeError: Cannot convert 1 to Decimal128
```

removing altogether

```
                list_of_dict[k] = Decimal128(v)
```

just gives the original 'not str' TypeError:

I'm sure it's something easy that i'm just not seeing. I know you can't

Comment: Provide a small sample of your data and I'll try and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the line at which an error is being raised:

```py
                list_of_dict[k] = Decimal128(str(v))
```

`list_of_dict` is a list, `k` is a key from one of the `dict`s. From your error message, `k` is evidently a string. If you're indexing a list, you should be using list indexes, not `dict` keys.

What you seem to want to do is to convert a single decimal value in one of the `dict`s to Decimal128. The current `dict` you are iterating through is in the variable `i`, so try changing the line above to this:

```py
                i[k] = Decimal128(str(v))
```

(You might also want to consider improving the name of the variable `i`, both to make it more descriptive, and also because `i`, `j`, `k` etc. are often used as loop counter variables containing integer values.)

Finally, I must state that this code hasn't been tested. I don't have a copy of MongoDB installed.