# How to store decimals and dates using PyMongo from a Python Dictionary (to MongoDB)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, decimal, pymongo

Here is a code fragment that I used to test.  I'm trying to determine what happens when you use dictionary vs JSON style, and when you use a variable.

```
    from decimal import * 
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    
    my_int_a = "21"
    my_int_b = 21
    
   row_dict = {}
    row_dict['key'] = 'my string (default)'
    row_dict['myInteger'] = int(21)
    row_dict['myInteger2'] = 21
    row_dict['myInteger3'] = my_int_a
    row_dict['myInteger4'] = my_int_b
    # row_dict['myCurrencyDecimal'] = Decimal(25.97)
    row_dict['myCurrencyDouble'] = 25.97
    row_dict['myDateInsertedFmt'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
    row_dict['myDateInsertedNow'] = datetime.datetime.now()

    db_collection_test_datatypes.insert_one(row_dict)    db_collection_test_datatypes.insert_one(row_dict)
    
    
    json_dict = {
        'key': 'my json key',
        'myInteger': 21,
        'myCurrencyDouble': 25.97
    }
    db_collection_test_datatypes.insert_one(json_dict)
```

This is what I see in the database:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("653052a351416c5223bbeee7"),
    "key": "my string (default)",
    "myInteger": NumberInt("21"),
    "myInteger2": NumberInt("21"),
    "myInteger3": "21",
    "myInteger4": NumberInt("21"),
    "myCurrencyDouble": 25.97,
    "myDateInsertedFmt": "2023-10-18T16:48:19.000Z",
    "myDateInsertedNow": ISODate("2023-10-18T16:48:19.411Z")
}    and 
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("65305109485c0394d26e8983"),
      "key": "my json key",
      "myInteger": NumberInt("21"),
      "myCurrencyDouble": 25.97
    }
```

NOTE: There is no ISODate wrapper on the formatted date.  Somewhere I saw that the above is the format to use for storing a date in MongoDB. So if I have a date, I need to load it to a date type. (I have changed this question several times since I first posted it, where it wasn't an ISODATE).

When I try to use the decimal (which is commented out above), I get this error:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object:
> Decimal('25.969999999999998863131622783839702606201171875'), of type:
> <class 'decimal.Decimal'>

Do I have to store the floating point value?

And Part 2 of my question, if I use JSON with quotes, then numbers arestored as strings?  JSON seems to lack standards, many JSONs I see have all values in quotes, even the numbers.  How would I deal with that?

In my actual application, I'm parsing a CSV into strings, but then I noticed that even the numbers were being stored as string instead of numbers, which I is why I wrote the above test and asked this question.

Comment: What happens if you use `row_dict['myDateInserted'] = datetime.datetime.now()`?

Comment: Reviewing `pymongo`'s [BSON Encoding and Decoding](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated question several times with more experiments.  I think this page will help clarify more: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/decimal128.html
Looks like originally MongoDB didn't have decimals but then they added it. 
But I'm specifically interested in how it works with Python dictionaries.

Comment: You may be interested in `pymongo`'s `TypeCodec` and `TypeRegistry`.  Luckily, the documentation Custom Types example deals specifically with [`Decimal` <-> `Decimal128` translation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/custom_type.html#custom-type-type-codec)

Comment: _"In my actual application, I'm parsing a CSV ..."_  You may be interested in [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) where you can specify column types on import, and [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict(orient="records")`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to prepare your data for import with `pymongo`.  If you just need to specify the CSV columns and their types, you might also consider [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) so you could go straight from CSV to a collection.

Answer (score 1):

For your date store as a string note that `strftime` as its name shown return a string.

The pymongo library include an automatic formating of datetime and store it straight into the right format in Mongo.

The same applies to float(not decimal) and int no need to cast because the type is dynamically asign in Python.

I'll recomand to use float as much as you can, and if you really need to use `Decimal` then you'll need to convert it to `Decimal128`.
This topic has already been related see : [Pymongo: Cannot encode object of type decimal.Decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456784/pymongo-cannot-encode-object-of-type-decimal-decimal)

Please let me know if you have some more questions i'll be happy to help you with that

Comment: Thanks, looks like these two lines will work.  Note you have to convert your number to a string to pass to the Decimal128. 

from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128
row_dict['myCurrencyDecimal'] = Decimal128(str(25.97))

Comment: Why do you recommend using float 'as much as you can'?  Will it ever change 25.97 to 25.9666666999 or similar?  And if so, you just round it again the your Python app?

Comment: Even if Decimal is more precise, it is less adaptable and more complicated to use. Float are more convenient and fast. Moreover If you store 25.97 you'll fetch 25.97. Float can change when doing calculation in python with them but it can be easely fix when less precision is required

Answer (score 0):

This is still a code fragment, but shows how to use the Decimal128.
NOTE: You must wrap it with str() function before passing to Decimal128.

```
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128

    row_dict = {}
    row_dict['key'] = 'my string (default)'
    row_dict['myInteger'] = int(21)
    row_dict['myInteger2'] = 21
    row_dict['myInteger3'] = my_int_a
    row_dict['myInteger4'] = my_int_b
    row_dict['myCurrencyDecimal'] = Decimal128(str(25.97))
    row_dict['myCurrencyDouble'] = 25.97
    row_dict['myDateInsertedFmt'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
    row_dict['myDateInsertedNow'] = datetime.datetime.now()

    db_collection_test_datatypes.insert_one(row_dict)
```

Creates this in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65305679b5fb74135f65c921"),
    "key": "my string (default)",
    "myInteger": NumberInt("21"),
    "myInteger2": NumberInt("21"),
    "myInteger3": "21",
    "myInteger4": NumberInt("21"),
    "myCurrencyDecimal": NumberDecimal("25.97"),
    "myCurrencyDouble": 25.97,
    "myDateInsertedFmt": "2023-10-18T17:04:41.000Z",
    "myDateInsertedNow": ISODate("2023-10-18T17:04:41.798Z")
}
```